# PrintDialog.Document don't exist

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

PrintDialog.Document don't exist as element in the drop down list from visual studio 2010;
Demonstration:

[image]

Comment: Ok, what's the question?

Comment: how to Access PrintDialog.Document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that scrollbar on the right?  Click and drag it down.

In case you're getting *way* too tired: it isn't PrintDialog.Document, it is PrintDialog.PrintDocument.  Take a break, have a beer, kiss the girl.

And, yes I completely agree, WPF sux for completely unnecessary property name changes.  You linked the wrong MSDN article.